# List files and folders into an array

Tags: php, arrays, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to list all the files within all sub-directories into a multi-dimensional array.

For example:

### Files structure

- Root/index.php
- Root/folder1/a.jpg
- Root/folder1/b.jpg
- Root/folder1/c.mov
- Root/folder2/aa.jpg
- Root/folder2/bb.jpg
- Root/folder2/cc.mov

I'm trying to get an array() like this...

```
$list = array(

     array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'folder'=> 'folder1',
            'imgs' => array('a.jpg', 'b.jpg')
     ),

     array(
            'type' => 'video',
            'folder'=> 'folder1',
            'video' => 'c.mov'
     ),

    array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'folder'=> 'folder2',
            'imgs' => array('aa.jpg', 'bb.jpg')
     ),

     array(
            'type' => 'video',
            'folder'=> 'folder2',
            'video' => 'cc.mov'
     ),

)
```

Comment: And your programming question is?

Answer (score 1):

As i guess you might be used Scandir function to list of files and folder and specific directory. using below recursive function you can get your result.

```
function listAllFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listAllFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listAllFolderFiles('Your main dir');
```

Comment: There's a mistake in your last line. It should be `listAllFolderFiles('Your main dir');`, and not `listFolderFiles('Your main dir');` - Otherwise, it will produce an error to undefined function.

Comment: ohh sorry i just updated..

Comment: Good work Liyakat ;-)

Comment: Added note: OP asked for bulleted list. I'm sure the OP will figure it out, to change the `<ol></ol>` **to** `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: yes or we can also manage with css to give good effect.

Comment: Exactly. There's usually more than one way to pretty things up, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecursiveIterator, to create a multi-dimensional array....

```
 $path = realpath('Root/');
 $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST); 

 $yourArray = array(); 

 foreach ($it as $FileInfo) { 
   $path = $FileInfo->isDir() 
     ? array($FileInfo->getFilename() => array()) 
     : array($FileInfo->getFilename()); 

  for ($depth = $it->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) { 
   $path = array($it->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path); 
  } 
 $yourArray = array_merge_recursive($yourArray, $path); 
 } 

 print_r($yourArray);
```